# Remove line from file

Tags: awk

I have data of 4 columns, 10000s rows. 
I am trying to remove rows whose 2nd column has values lesser than the previous lines's 3rd column.

```
chr1        10        20        3 
chr1        15        30        9 
chr1        55        60        1
```

Comment: `totally new to awk` --> check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: I count 12 columns...?

Comment: @JeffSchaller 4 columns in 3 rows.

Comment: The previous line's 3rd column in the input or in the output? IOW, what happens if a line is deleted? In the above example, is the 55 in the third line to be compared with the 30 of the second line or (since the second line is deleted in the output) with the 20 of the first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '$2 >= prev; {prev=$3}' file.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `awk <commands> file.txt`: run awk on `file.txt`.
- `$2 >= prev`: check if the second field `$2` is greater or equal than the contents of variable `prev`. (This is unset for the first line.) If this is true, then awk defaults to printing the entire line. (i.e. if it is less, then delete the line.)
- `{prev=$3}`: store the contents of the third field `$3` in the variable `prev`.

This then repeats for the next line. awk will compare the second field with `prev`, which now contains the third field from the line before. A couple of things to note:

- I'm not sure what you wanted for the first line, so I'd just manually include/exclude it as you see fit.
- If the data are actually tab delimited, just add the following flag to awk to let it know: `-F'\t'`.

Comment: Should be `$2 > prev;`: if the value is less, the line is deleted.

Comment: @Nick Oops, nice catch. I should have read the question more carefully.

Comment: Thank you @Sparhawk and @Nick . It did work. Although when I added `-F'\t'`, it showed this error `awk: syntax error at source line 1 awk: bailing out at source line 1'. Without the flag it did work fine and removed 44 lines.

Comment: @PDM I'm not sure what that could be. Maybe it's a version issue; you could try `-vFS='\t'` instead. If this answer works, then please click the tick on the left (and the upvote arrow if you so desire). Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, I did that. If I may ask, how does awk know $3 is the third field of the previous line, not the current one?

Comment: @PDM The whole set of commands are run repeatedly for each line of the input file. Hence, for each line, it will do the comparison (and possible print), and _then_ write to the `prev` variable. So when awk processes the next line, the comparison occurs first, using the `prev` that was stored earlier (i.e. the line before). Only after the comparison will it re-write to the `prev` variable. (P.S. thanks for the upvote, but there should be a tick to click as well. Cheers.)